# Laravel messenger issue

Tags: php, laravel, oop, chat

I have been following along with https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger
to install it. I have got everything I believe in the correct place, but I think that I have got some error in my namespacing in my MessagesController  as im getting the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in MessagesController.php line 13:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found

MessagesController.php contents.
```

-

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Cmgmyr\Messenger\Models\Message;
use Cmgmyr\Messenger\Models\Participant;
use Cmgmyr\Messenger\Models\Thread;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show all of the message threads to the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index()
{
```

I just included the file up and past the line with the error, obviously there is more in there.

Am I missing something from the installation?

I am confused. Its clearly the line where the class opens.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'messages'], function () {
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'messages', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@index']);
Route::get('create', ['as' => 'messages.create', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@create']);
Route::post('/', ['as' => 'messages.store', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@store']);
Route::get('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.show', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@show']);
Route::put('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.update', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@update']);
```

});

Comment: do you have another controller  in the same directory called Controller? and did you change your app name?

Comment: Yes, its currently in my controllers folder, and yes i did

Comment: try use nameofyourapp\Http\Controllers\Controller;

Comment: now getting Class personalpage\Http\Controllers\MessagesController does not exist. mmmm do i need to move the MessagesController now?

Comment: post the full error can you pls?

Comment: ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
    Class personalpage\Http\Controllers\MessagesController does not exist

Comment: Ok i realised how dumb i sounded asking if i need to move the controller now. The problem lies in the way the route is defined with a named app i guess.

Comment: can you share your routes file?

Comment: Are you sure that the file path is  ```app\Http\Controllers\MessageController.php```

Comment: try to change your namespaces (change the app to 'apppersonalpage') and you changed the app name using php artisan app:name SocialNet right?

Comment: So you mean to change the name again? And yes i changed it by that method. @Xdevnull yes the path is 'app\HTTP\Controllers\MessagesController.php'

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Probably ```use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;``` would solve his problem but it's not required if the file setting in base directory of Controllers

Comment: @Jamesmcconnon try to add ```use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;``` under the namespace

Comment: FatalErrorException in MessagesController.php line 14:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found back to original error

Comment: Do you have ```Controller.php``` in ```App\Http\Controllers\``` folder?!?!

Comment: @xdevnull i asked him that and he said he does, check first comments

Comment: Ok so i changed the namespace again and for some reason its all working? there was a small error not referencing the user class in there aswell so i had to run use Socialnet\User as User; also.